# Coloring cells that have matching text

Tags: excel, vba, colors, match, conditional-formatting

I have a set of required items spread across A1:H40 and a buylist in col. J. I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621509/macro-to-color-specific-cells-with-specific-data), but I'm a bit overwhelmed.

How do I color the cells across A1:H40 with text that match the ones in col. J?

Is there a way to incorporate this function into a button so that it can be applied to other spreadsheets as well (or any other efficient way)?

In addition, is there a way to design a fool-proof script that eliminates the excessive spaces at the end of each cell due to typing errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear existing CF from and select A1:H40 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF($J:$J,A1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting of your choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Seems to me not to require a button to make this any easier, and 'spaces' is a completely different Q that should not be combined with another.

Comment: Why is A1 used to determine the range, is it programmed to apply to all selected cells if I use the top left cell?